# ECEF frames in astropy/healpix?

Tags: coordinate-systems, astropy, healpy

I went through the astropy documentation and concluded that
there are no native ECEF (earth-centered, earth-fixed) frames with lon, lat coordinates that can be converted into equatorial coordinates RA, dec if the time is given. Is this true?

Eventually, I'd like to create a map using:

`map = HEALPix(nside=NSIDE, order='nested', frame=MY_REF_FRAME())`

`MY_REF_FRAME = ITRS` is apparently not an option.

I'd be grateful if someone can help me to find if there is a way this can be defined with a recent version of astropy.

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

HEALPix itself and https://astropy-healpix.readthedocs.io is mostly about the HEALPix pixels in one given sky frame.

For transformations between different sky coordinate systems you should look to [astropy.coordinates](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/index.html).

I'm not familiar with ECEF, but you might be able to do the computation you want using the existing ICRS and ITRF frames (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49325584/498873).

Comment: Apparently ITRS only have a cartesian representation (x, y, z). I'm looking for a spherical representation (lon, lat). Is there a way to include this to the ITRS class?

Comment: I haven't used ITRS or know if it has peculiarities. This works: `SkyCoord(42, 43, unit='deg', frame='icrs').transform_to('itrs').spherical`. Maybe you have to transform between spherical and cartesian representation yourself in this case? http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/representations.html

Comment: Thanks! Let me post here the reverse transformation for memory: `coord.ITRS( coord.SphericalRepresentation(lon= 0.0 *u.deg ,lat = 0.0 * u.deg, distance = 1 * u.m), obstime=Time('2018-12-03 14:00:00')).tranform_to(coord.ICRS)`

Comment: With astropy 3.0.5, this command leads to an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'` in `numpy/ma/core.py`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the ValueError you mention. When I paste your code snippet I get `AttributeError: 'ITRS' object has no attribute 'tranform_to'`. If you have a complete code snippet that one can copy & paste & execute to try and reproduce the `ValueError` in numpy/ma/core.py, you could put it here or better yet in the Astropy issue tracker. Probably exact Numpy and Astropy version numbers are needed to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post an answer to last @Christoph comment here so that I can paste the full code. This is the code and error I get:

```
In [1]: import astropy.coordinates as coord                                                                                                                                                           
In [2]: import astropy.units as u                                                                                                                                                                     
In [3]: from astropy.time import Time                                                                                                                                                                 
In [4]: coord.ITRS( coord.SphericalRepresentation(lon= 0.0 *u.deg ,lat = 0.0 * u.deg, distance = 1 * u.m), obstime=Time('2018-12-03 14:00:00')).transform_to(coord.ICRS)                              

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1d50da4d3855> in <module>
----> 1 coord.ITRS( coord.SphericalRepresentation(lon= 0.0 *u.deg ,lat = 0.0 * u.deg, distance = 1 * u.m), obstime=Time('2018-12-03 14:00:00')).transform_to(coord.ICRS)

~/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/coordinates/baseframe.py in transform_to(self, new_frame)
   1165             msg = 'Cannot transform from {0} to {1}'
   1166             raise ConvertError(msg.format(self.__class__, new_frame.__class__))
-> 1167         return trans(self, new_frame)
   1168 
   1169     def is_transformable_to(self, new_frame):
...
   474             # In case we want to convert 1e20 to int.
   475             try:
--> 476                 fill_value = np.array(fill_value, copy=False, dtype=ndtype)
   477             except OverflowError:
   478                 # Raise TypeError instead of OverflowError. 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'


In [6]: astropy.__version__                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[6]: '3.0.5'

In [8]: numpy.__version__                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[8]: '1.15.3'
```